# Text positioning behaves differently on MAC and Windows

Tags: html, css, windows, macos

I got some strange problems with text positioning in MAC and Windows. Both are using Chrome. I have a print here.

[image]

I can't seem to position the text in the middle, this occurs on several elements in the page. This is the html code.

```
<div align="center" class="tooltip px14 UnBC-font">
             ABOUT
             <div class="arrow"></div>
</div> <!-- tooltip -->
```

and the css

```
 .navigation .tooltip{
    width:70px;
    height:20px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:-80px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:2px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    color:#2d312c;
    display:none;
 }

.navigation .tooltip .arrow
{
    position:absolute;
    width:4px;
    height:7px;
    background-image:url(../images/main/white-little-arrow.png);
    right:0px;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-3px;
    margin-right:-4px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `line-height` and see if that helps :)

Comment: Looks like it did the trick, i'm sure i tried it before. But now it works, thanks !